# Как улучшить код для задачи на Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Решил тут одну задачу на питоне, но решение кажется громоздким для нее. Хотел бы узнать, как его можно улучшить? (можно побольше объяснений)

Пытался воспользоваться модулем `itertools`, но не нашел там подходящего решения.

Задание:

На вход дается 2 числа: n и m

**Напишите программу, которая выводит путь, по которому, двигаясь интервалом длины m по заданному массиву, концом будет являться первый элемент. Началом одного интервала является конец предыдущего. Путь - массив из начальных элементов полученных интервалов.**

Пример 1:

n = 4, m = 3

Решение:

Круговой массив: 1234. При длине обхода 3 получаем интервалы: 123, 341.

Полученный путь: 13.

Пример 2:

n = 5, m = 4

Решение:

Круговой массив: 12345. При длине обхода 4 получаем интервалы: 1234, 4512, 2345, 5123, 3451.

Полученный путь: 14253.

Параметры передаются в качестве аргументов командной строки.

Например, для последнего примера на вход подаются аргументы: 5 4.

Ожидаемый вывод в консоль: 14253.

Вот то, что я накидал, но мне не нравится:

```
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    one_List = m * [int(i) for i in range(1, n + 1)]
    two_List = [' ']
    three_List = []
    cnt = 0
    while two_List[-1] != 1:
        two_List.clear()
        for j in range(cnt, m + cnt):
            two_List.append(one_List[j])
            cnt += 1 
        two_List_copy = two_List.copy()
        three_List.append(two_List_copy)
        cnt -= 1
    for k in range(len(three_List)):
        print(three_List[k][0], end='')
```

Comment: Как я понял, требуется записать путь именно из первых чисел полученных строк-путей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы знаете модульную арифметику, то сможете записать функцию, которая возвращает следующую цифру в пути по текущей:

```
def next_i(i):
    return 1 + (i + m - 2) % n
```

Таблица для `n = 5, m = 4`:

> ```
> i    next_i(i)
> 1         4
> 2         5
> 3         1
> 4         2
> 5         3
> ```

Имея такую функцию несложно написать программу, которая начав с единицы выводит следующие цифры пока снова не встретит единицу:

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())

i = 1
while True:
    print(i, end='')
    i = 1 + (i + m - 2) % n
    if i == 1:
        break
print()
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно используя генератор.
На первой итерации он всегда возвращает 1. А дальше идёт по последовательности чисел с шагом `m-1`. Но так как у нас не бесконечная последовательность, а "зацикленная", чтобы это сэмулировать, надо просто брать остаток от деления на длину последовательности. Но и плюс 1, т.к. последовательность в Питоне от нуля, а в задаче от единицы.
Генератор заканчивает свою работу когда очередной член последовательности будет равен 1.

```
def seq(n,m):
    yield 1
    for i in range(m-1, n*m, m-1):
        v = i % n + 1
        if v == 1: return
        yield v

print(list(seq(n,m)))
```

Answer (score 2):

я бы предложил почитать про модуль `collections` и метод `deque`. С ним вариант решения мог бы быть таким:

Исходные:

```
from collections import deque

lst = '1234'
step = 3
```

решение:

```
arr = deque(lst)
res = list(arr[0])
arr.rotate(-(step-1))
while arr[0] != lst[0]:
    res.append(arr[0])
    arr.rotate(-(step-1))
```

ну и `res` теперь будет:

```
['1', '3']
```

Answer (score 0):

С применением itertools

```
start=5
end=4
import itertools

#start to string
start_str=''.join(map(str,[it for it in range(1,start+1)]))
#get all perm
allresult=itertools.permutations(start_str, end)


def checking(sequence):
    '''
    get sequence and return true if it ok
    '''
    for it in range(0,len(sequence)-1):
        if int(sequence[it])+1!=int(sequence[it+1]) :
            if sequence[it+1]=='1' and sequence[it]==str(start):
                continue
            return False
    return True

#drop wrong result
total_result=list(filter(checking,allresult))

print(total_result)
[('1', '2', '3', '4'), ('2', '3', '4', '5'), ('3', '4', '5', '1'), ('4', '5', '1', '2'), ('5', '1', '2', '3')]
```