# Python NOOB Как передать переменную из одной функции в другую. Помогите с тестовым заданием, плз)))

Tags: python, python-3.x

Всем привет!
Второй день бьюсь над задачей из тестового задания в ПерфомансЛаб...

Задание такое:
*Круговой массив - массив из элементов, в котором по достижению конца массива следующим
элементом будет снова первый. Mассив задается числом n, то есть представляет собой числа от 1
до n.
Пример кругового массива для n=3:
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
Напишите программу, которая выводит путь, по которому, двигаясь интервалом длины m по
заданному массиву, концом будет являться первый элемент.
Началом одного интервала является конец предыдущего. Путь - массив из начальных элементов
полученных интервалов.
Пример 1:
n = 4, m = 3
Решение:
Круговой массив: 1234. При длине обхода 3 получаем интервалы: 123, 341.
Полученный путь: 13.
Пример 2:
n = 5, m = 4
Решение:
Круговой массив: 123456. При длине обхода 4 получаем интервалы: 1234, 4512, 2345, 5123, 3451.
Полученный путь: 14253.
Параметры передаются в качестве аргументов командной строки.
Например, для последнего примера на вход подаются аргументы: 5 4
Ожидаемый вывод в консоль: 14253*

Откровенно, питон изучал пару лет назад, поэтому, много чего забыл и ещё больше не знаю, так что, тут мои полномочия всё...

Родил вот такой код, но не могу решить задачу над передачей переменной mass дальше в цикле `while`.

Саму переменную mass объявлял и глобально, и локально в разных местах кода, и через `global` вместо `return`.

Буду признателен, если укажете на ошибки..

````
m = int(input("Enter period (M): "))
startfrom = 1
path = []
mass = []

def pathfunction(n, m, startfrom):
    firstitem = 1
    lastitem = 0
    while firstitem != lastitem:
        period(n, m, startfrom)
        firstitem = mass[0]
        path.append(mass)
        lastitem = mass
        startfrom = mass
    return path

def period(n, m, startfrom):
    mass = []
    j = 0
    for i in range(m):
        if startfrom + j < n:
            mass.append(startfrom + j)
            j += 1
        elif startfrom + j >= n:
            mass.append(startfrom + j)
            startfrom = 1
            j = 0
    return mass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pathfunction(n, m, startfrom)```
````

Comment: Ну вы же возвращаете переменную из функции, так принимайте её там, куда она возвращается: `mass = period(n, m, startfrom)`, только у вас это и локальная и глобальная переменная, я логику не понял, может это две разных переменных должно быть.

Comment: И вот это `lastitem = mass` непонятно - вы индексу присваиваете список, тут что-то не так.

Comment: вот это решение из задачи кажется не верным: "_Пример 2: n = 5, m = 4 Решение: Круговой массив: 123456_" Откуда там 6-ка?

Comment: задача решалась [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1341240/209304)

Comment: Спасибо за советы! @CrazyElf, благодарю за наводку про присваивание списка..

Comment: @Dmitry, спасибо за ссылку на решение задачи) 
Сделал по-своему, не так красиво, как в приведенном решении, но зато я понимаю свой алгоритм)
Впредь, буду лучше искать ответ на свой вопрос)

Comment: @endyrlx на здоровье, не забудьте оценить ответы по ссылке, который оказались вам полезны!